# How to create an Image at construction of a UIImageView

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I have a custom UIImageView and when it constructed I would like to create an in memory or cached to the iDevice Image that is a Filled Rectangle of a specific color and then set it to the UIImageView's Image property.

I know how to draw this on a UIImage by overriding the Draw method and it would just draw on the current CGContext. However since I want to do this at the time the UIImageView is constructed I don't actually have a context I can draw on or anything since it is not visible yet.

Simply put I am wondering if there is a way to do this programmatically at construction of the custom UIImageView when the app starts before anything is displayed to the screen.

I am okay with answers in C# or Objective-C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I can help you with the UIKit / Objective-C approach. As for .NET, I don't have the foggiest. UIKit has a few useful functions for programmatically generating UIImages. What you'll need to do is something like the following:

```
- (UIImage*)generateImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(someCGSize);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Draw whatever you want here with ctx, just like an overridden drawRect.

    UIImage* generatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return generatedImage;
}
```

Just make sure you call such a method from the main thread. That's the only caveat I can think of.

[Edit] The C#/MonoTouch version is:

```
UIImage GenerateImage ()
{
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (new RectangleF (0, 0, 100, 100));
    var ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

    // Draw into the ctx anything you want.
    var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem work during object construction while the app is launching. That seems to only work when called form a Draw method, other wise I get a nil CGContextRef.  I am good when I am dealing with UIGraphics and CGContext. The issue is that those don't seem to be available if nothing has been displayed on the screen, and it seems the UIView in question also has to be visible on the screen. I want to be able to create a UIImage without a Current Context basically so that it can be done during an object construction and before it is displayed.

Comment: I think what I may be asking is can I create a UIGraphic CGContext for "off screen" drawing?

Comment: @Rodney: That's odd. I've used this method faithfully for UIImage generation at many point's in the app's lifecycle. Now that I'm around a capable machine again, I tested this from -application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and I get a valid image. I'm not familiar with monotouch, but it seems likely that when you say a "Draw" method you mean an override of the UIView -drawRect: method. Can you verify that?

Comment: @Matt Yes the drawRect is the method I mean. I have tried to get a CGContext from several places including a constructor and anytime the call are not from within the scope of drawRect or a method called by drawRect I get a nil CGContext.  It made me think that there is no concept of "multiple" buffering and drawing "off screen" in iOS SDK.  However if you have gotten a not nil context in a object constructor a a method not called from drawRect then I may be doing something wrong and I will give it another try and double check my syntax and calls to make sure I am not doing something stupid.

Comment: @Matt Sure enough I did a simple test using the exact method sample you provided and drew a simple image and I called it only from the constructor and it worked great.  I must have been doing something wrong before.  Thanks Matt!

Comment: Oh, great, because I was out of suggestions =)